# How to save data from google review form to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, google-sheets, google-api

I need to save data from Google Reviews to SQL Server 2014. I have googled it and had no success using Google API.

I have created a table in SQL Server and displayed when data is available, just save more and everything will be fine okay, thanks.